# The type of transformer having 6 output terminal and 2 input terminal, with an insulated conductors projected from its top?

Tags: transformer

I got a transformer from my system SMPS. I have heard about 2 terminal input, 3 terminal output transformers. But the particular one i got is having 6 output terminal. Also, there is an insulated conductor from its top position. What type of transformer it is. How it is connected? 
  Also, there is 3 to 4 and 3 to 5 terminal transformer. What it might be? 
Please explain.

Comment: A picture of the part would help. A schematic of the circuit where you found it would be even better. A part number would be best, in terms of being able to give you a sure answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A picture would help, but it can be one of two things. The first, it's just a multi-tap transformer. Instead of tapping just the high and low ends (two output terminals) or a high, center and low (three output, center tapped), it is tapped in multiple places, providing n number of different voltages, depending on where on the secondary coil it is tapped.

The second type can be a transformer with two secondary coils, also center tapped. Essentially two transformers in one package.

Answer (score 1):

The additional connections are likely taps to the middle of the windings on either end. If you measure the resistance with an ohmmeter, it's usually possible to figure out which tap is what, since the length of the wire corresponds to its resistance. Be sure you make a good contact with your meter probes, since the contact resistance can be significant relative to the small resistance of the wires in question.

These tapped transformers are often used in SMPS to generate multiple output voltages, just as they would for a mains transformer. If the primary:secondary ratio is 1:1, but the secondary has a tap 1/3rd of the way through, then you can also get 1/3rd of the output voltage off that tap. Cross-regulation of the output voltages can be a design challenge, but one tapped transformer and SMPS is cheaper than multiple, independent SMPS.

Answer (score 0):

most of SMPS transformers are custom, designed for a particular power supply. Those 6 outputs can be 3 independent coils, or just one with taps or any other combination.
Sometimes one of the output coils is used for regulation.
More than taking pictures of the transformer, which is just ferrite and copper wires, it's better to have a look at the circuit, either in operation and not, to get more information about output voltages, secondary rectifiers, currents, frequencies, etc.